# Make [codegolf] a synonym for [code-golf]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I would like to propose a new synonym: [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codegolf). 
It should be merged with [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) to avoid confusion errors.

I'm not allowed to create this by myself because the difference is the dash only, so I raise it on Meta. I'm not sure if this is the right place to propose for tags.

Comment: Yes please. Very good idea.

Comment: @m654 We have all faced our worst enemy: [tag:codegolf]. It confuses us suddenly, it makes our challenges off-topic, it's cruel. It's bad. It's sad. **It should have always been merged to good ol' [tag:code-golf].**

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Actually, if you go to the [code-golf] tag wiki you can vote to create a synonym for it. That is what you are looking for I think.

Comment: Why do we need to create [tag:codegolf] if you want to merge it with [tag:code-golf] anyway?

Comment: As you're typing the tag name code-golf should show up, just click that.

Comment: Why on earth does this post have a negative score?

Comment: @dorukayhan Downvotes on meta signify that you disagree with something or that a discussion or feature wouldn't be useful.

Comment: @AlexA. "Just click that" is not a solution for me. Some people are lazy.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ The tag synonym system is not in place because of your laziness. If you *really* want to type less, you can type `o<Tab><Enter>` instead. Requesting the creation of a useless tag simply because "Some people are lazy" is unreasonable.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ And no, [voting is different on meta](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). Alex is objectively right.

Comment: @Doorknob I said "alex-is-**rw**ong" on purpose, indicating that I both agree with the meta votes, but disagree with the fact that comment can't be downvoted.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ what??? ([also.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3615/180276))

Answer (score 6):

> to avoid confusion errors

> I'm not allowed to create this by myself because the difference is the dash only

Looks like the system is doing its job. Specifically, the message you should be getting is

> You are attempting to create the tag [codegolf]; however the tag [code-golf] already exists!

I don't see any potential for confusion there.

Synonyms are created when two tags are being used for the same purpose, making searching, categorization, etc. difficult. Since [codegolf] cannot even be created, adding a synonym would be pointless.

Comment: This is a real problem on everything but tags in the tag section of a question. You're not covering the other areas of a post where this error could occur.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ elaborate?

Comment: You are saying that the system works, although \[tag:codegolf] is possible: [tag:codegolf].

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ So don't type that. Should there be tags for every possible typo of code-golf as well? [tag:code-gofl]? [tag:cdoe-golf]? [tag:cpde-golf]?